unable to input data input the input box by selenium as I can see there is name and id inside the script
I am unable to input data into the username and password by using the findelementId or findelementName in selenium web driver, however I can see there is name and id inside the script.
website= https://www.propsocial.my/en/users/sign_in
<input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="form-control" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">

and
<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="************" class="form-control" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">

My code is very simple.
Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
'set driver2 = new Selenium.we
'driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://www.propsocial.my/en/users/sign_in"

'driver.Window.Maximize

driver.Wait 500
driver.FindElementById("user_email").SendKeys "abc@gmail.com"

driver.Wait 500
driver.FindElementByName("user[password]").SendKeys "abc001"

How to solve the above problem to input username and password into the column

What is the error message you are seeing please? With Chrome and chrome driver there is possibly a security feature to stop you entering a username and password automatically.

Hi @terry, you are not able to interact with the elements because there are more than 1 web elements with id=user_email and name=user[password]. One option is to use xpath to locate/target these elements. For example, for email you can use //input[@placeholder='Enter your email address'] and for password //input[@placeholder='Insert your password'] can be used. Hope this solves your issue.

@Pramesh, it is very useful code, you helped me to solved my problem, very appreciated it

The problem is that there are 3 instances of user_email on the page. You can use a CSS selector to find the email field,
#new_user #user_email

and a similar CSS selector for the password field,
#new_user #user_password

# indicates an ID and a space indicates a descendant in CSS selector syntax.
So your code would change to
driver.Wait 500
driver.FindElementByCss("#new_user #user_email").SendKeys "abc@gmail.com"

driver.Wait 500
driver.FindElementByCss("#new_user #user_password").SendKeys "abc001"


fantastic! It gave me more solution, and I learned more, appreciated it

May I know how to upvote or mark it as accepted? Sorry, I am new here

@terrybogard Both are described in the link I posted in my last comment.
